# What does 遍 mean in 小编遍搜多名?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, internet-slang

In the following sentence:

> 小编**遍搜多名**日本时尚博主的推文和美图，盘点了一下2017秋季日系时尚关键词，和爱美的**盆友**共享。

I understand the meaning, which is something like the following:

> (Our) bloggers search for recommendations and pictures posted by many popular Japanese bloggers, and compiled the crucial points on Japanese fasion on fall 2017. So here we share them with you.

However, I don't understand some grammatical points:

1. What is 遍? How does it function as a grammar here?
2. 搜多名 is I think the abbreviation of 搜索很多有名, but is this correct? In that case, is it common to abbreviate the long words to such a compact one?
3. What does the 盆友 mean? My dictionary and [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E7%9B%86%E5%8F%8B) doesn't have the entry, FYI.

Comment: Well, rearding 3, it is [likely a typo for 朋友](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1987481065682219307.html). In Chinese there are so many these sorts of mis-typing...

Comment: 盆友 originally is a mis-typing, but since more and more comes, it then becomes a net slang. A similar one is 童鞋, which is actually 同学.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [遍](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/xs/904D.htm) means `allover;everywhere` here. `遍搜` means `search allover/everywhere`. Basically it has the same meaning with `搜遍`, but with the `遍` being put ahead OP wanted to emphasize the degree of how many bloggers he checked.
2. `多名` is not the abbreviation of `很多有名`, but just `很多名`, i.e. `many`. `名` is just the measure word of the people, i.e. 博主.
3. [盆友](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9B%86%E5%8F%8B) is a net slang, means `朋友`.

Comment: Thanks, so in this case 名 doesn't include the connotation for "famous" or "popular"?

Comment: Do you have any sources regarding 很多名 means "many"? There seems to [have no such result](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=%E5%BE%88%E5%A4%9A%E5%90%8D+meaning&oq=%E5%BE%88%E5%A4%9A%E5%90%8D+meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2074.4356.0.4464.22.10.0.0.0.0.284.1223.0j1j4.5.0....0...1.1j4.64.psy-ab..17.3.754.0..0j0i67k1j0i30k1j0i12i30k1.0.0LO6TTycVCo).

Comment: @Blaszard Yes. `名` is just the measure word for the people `博主`.

Comment: @Blaszard 很多名, not 很有名.

Comment: Ah, sorry it was a typo. But the linked search result shows it as "很多名", so my point still holds true.

Comment: Ah, measure word! That makes sense, thank for your answer.

Comment: Is the verb here 遍搜? Or is it 遍 (adverb) + 搜 (verb)?

Comment: @Blaszard The verb is `搜`, `遍` is used as modifier.